# How can I stop Nuxt fetching AJAX data when building for SSR?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt 2 project with the following config:

```
target: 'static',
ssr: true,
fetchOnServer: false,
```

In some of my components I have a `fetch()` hook which fetches API data. I want this data to be fetched only and ever on the client, not by the server when building my site via `npm run generate`.

This should be achievable, [according to Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching), by setting`fetchOnServer` to falsy.

> When `fetchOnServer` is falsy (false or returns false), `fetch` will be called only on client-side ...

And yet, this is happening. When I build, I end up with the following file, which contains pre-fetched API data.

```
\dist\_nuxt\static\1677866567\payload.js
```

How can I tell Nuxt not to do any fetching when building, if not by setting `fetchOnServer` to false?